# Powershell - Export-ModuleMember doesn't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I'm new with PowerShell and I've just started to create my own module.
I created the script & manifest files and placed them into the directory `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\` who is one listed of the `$env:PSModulePath` command.

I can import and remove the module as well but **it's not recognized as an applet or command** when I try to call one of the function.

I use the Import-Module command :

```
Import-Module MyModule
```

My script file is something like this :

```
function MyFunction() {}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

And my manifest looks like this :

```
FunctionsToExport = '*'
```

Do I need to write all of the exported functions into the manifest ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so after a few hours I found the answer :
[ExportedCommand empty custom module PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/questions/724490/exportedcommand-empty-custom-module-powershell)

You need to put `RootModule = 'MyModule.psm1'` into the manifest.

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

for me, the following ( based on Mica's answer) worked:

1. Change the RootModule as Mica suggested in the psd1 file to the psm1 file.
2. Use the Import-Module -Force MyModule command

(with the '-Force' flag:
"This parameter causes a module to be loaded, or reloaded, over top of the current one." as said at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.1#examples)

Answer (score 0):

**To export everything:**

Module manifest (.psd1):

```
FunctionsToExport = '*'
```

Module script file (.psm1):

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

**To restrict what gets exported:**

Module manifest (.psd1):

```
FunctionsToExport = 'Foo', 'Bar'
```

Module script file (.psm1):

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function Foo, Bar
```

Note that if quotes are not used in this specific way, it will not work, and no error will be reported.